# Place 30-574 Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps    
module stopwatch(
    input clock,
    input reset,
    input increment,
    input start,
    output [6:0] seg,
    output dp,
    output [3:0] an
    );

    reg [3:0] reg_d0, reg_d1, reg_d2, reg_d3; //registers that will hold the individual counts
    reg [22:0] ticker;
    wire click;


    //the mod 1kHz clock to generate a tick ever 0.001 second

    always @ (posedge (clock) or posedge (reset))
    begin
        if(reset)
        begin
            ticker <= 0;
        end
        else 
        begin
            if (start)
            begin
                if(ticker == (100000 - 1)) //if it reaches the desired max value reset it
                    ticker <= 0;
                else if (increment)
                    ticker <= ticker;
                else
                    ticker <= ticker + 1;
            end 
        end
    end

    //increment a second everytime rising edge of down button
    reg [3:0] inc_temp;
    always @ (posedge (increment)) 
    begin
        if (reg_d3 == 9)
            inc_temp = 0;
        else
            inc_temp = reg_d3 + 1;
    end

    assign click = ((ticker == (100000 - 1))?1'b1:1'b0); //click to be assigned high every 0.001 second

    //update data start from here
    always @ (posedge (clock) or posedge (reset))
    begin
        if(reset)
        begin
            reg_d0 <= 0;
            reg_d1 <= 0;
            reg_d2 <= 0;
            reg_d3 <= 0;
        end

        else
        begin
            if (increment)
                begin
                    reg_d3 <= inc_temp;
                    reg_d0 <= reg_d0;
                    reg_d1 <= reg_d1;
                    reg_d2 <= reg_d2;    
                end
                else if (click) //increment at every click
                begin
                    if(reg_d0 == 9) //xxx9 - 1th milisecond
                    begin
                        reg_d0 <= 0;
                        if (reg_d1 == 9) //xx99 - 10th milisecond
                        begin
                            reg_d1 <= 0;
                            if (reg_d2 == 9) //x999 - 100th milisecond
                            begin
                                reg_d2 <= 0;
                                if(reg_d3 == 9) //9999 - The second digit
                                    reg_d3 <= 0;
                                else
                                    reg_d3 <= reg_d3 + 1;
                            end
                            else
                                reg_d2 <= reg_d2 + 1;
                        end

                        else
                            reg_d1 <= reg_d1 + 1;
                    end

                    else
                        reg_d0 <= reg_d0 + 1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    reg_d3 <= reg_d3;
                    reg_d0 <= reg_d0;
                    reg_d1 <= reg_d1;
                    reg_d2 <= reg_d2;
                end
        end

    end



    //Mux for display 4 7segs LEDs
    localparam N = 18; 
    reg [N-1:0]count;
    always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
    begin
        if (reset)
            count <= 0;
        else
            count <= count + 1;
    end

    reg [6:0]sseg;
    reg [3:0]an_temp;
    reg reg_dp;
    always @ (*)
        begin
            case(count[N-1:N-2])
                2'b00 :
                begin
                    sseg = reg_d0;
                    an_temp = 4'b1110;
                    reg_dp = 1'b1;
                end

                2'b01:
                begin
                    sseg = reg_d1;
                    an_temp = 4'b1101;
                    reg_dp = 1'b0;
                end

                2'b10:
                begin
                    sseg = reg_d2;
                    an_temp = 4'b1011;
                    reg_dp = 1'b1;
                end

                2'b11:
                begin
                    sseg = reg_d3;
                    an_temp = 4'b0111;
                    reg_dp = 1'b0;
                end
            endcase
        end
    assign an = an_temp;

    //update the data to display to LEDs
    reg [6:0] sseg_temp;
    always @ (*)
    begin
        case(sseg)
            4'd0 : sseg_temp = 7'b1000000;
            4'd1 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111001;
            4'd2 : sseg_temp = 7'b0100100;
            4'd3 : sseg_temp = 7'b0110000;
            4'd4 : sseg_temp = 7'b0011001;
            4'd5 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010010;
            4'd6 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000010;
            4'd7 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111000;
            4'd8 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000000;
            4'd9 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010000;
            default : sseg_temp = 7'b0111111; //dash
        endcase
    end
    assign seg = sseg_temp;
    assign dp = reg_dp;
endmodule
```

I'm trying to design a stop watch, but I'm stuck at the increment thing. The intent is when I press `increment`(a button), the `reg_d3` will increment by one and hold its state until the button is released. I'm able to make the clock stop when the button is pressed, but I can't update the `reg_d3`. I always receive

> [Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG

I don't know why; I use increment in the clkdivider just find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to this part of your code:

```
always @ (posedge (increment)) 
    begin
        if (reg_d3 == 9)
            inc_temp = 0;
        else
            inc_temp = reg_d3 + 1;
    end
```

You are basically using an input signal as a clock, and that is completely discouraged when designing for a FPGA. The P&R tries to re-route an `IO` pin to a `BUFG` (global buffer) inside the FPGA so it can be used as a clock.

For FPGA design, you should use one clock signal for all your `always @(posedge...)` constructions, and use input signals to conditionally load/update the register.

To do that, you have first to synchronize your `increment` signal to your `clk`, so avoiding metastability issues:

```
reg incr1=1'b0, incr2=1'b0;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  incr1 <= increment;
  incr2 <= incr1;
end
wire increment_synched = incr2;
```

Then, deglitch `increment_synched` and detect a rising edge in it:

```
reg [15:0] incrhistory = 16'h0000;
reg incr_detected = 1'b0;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  incrhistory <= { incrhistory[14:0] , increment_synched };
  if (incrhistory == 16'b0011111111111111)
    incr_detected <= 1'b1;
  else
    incr_detected <= 1'b0;
end
```

To detect a valid rising edge, we store a history of the last 16 values of `increment_synched`. When a valid steady change from 0 to 1 is produced, the history pattern will match the pattern `0011111111111111`. Then, and only then, we signal it by raising `incr_detected` to 1. The next clock cycle, the history pattern won't match the above sequence, and `incr_detected` will go down to 0 again.

Prior to that, multiple bounces in the push button `increment` is connected to would cause many transitions, leading to many increments. Using a pattern matching like that eliminates those glitches caused by multiple bounces.  With 1Khz clock as you seem to use, this pattern should be enough.

Now you can use `incr_detected` in your original code, `incr_detected` wil be 1 for just a single `clk` cycle.

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  if (incr_detected) begin
    if (reg_d3 == 9)
      inc_temp = 0;
    else
      inc_temp = reg_d3 + 1;
  end
end
```

You can test these additions using the following simulation:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/AQY

What you will see there is a module that takes your `increment` input signal from the outside, and generate a glitch-free one-cycle pulse when the input signal makes a final transition from low to high level.

Actually, I've written two versions. The second one tries to mimic the behaviour of a monostable, so the input won't be sampled for a specific period of time after the first low to high transition is detected.

You will see that the second version produces a pulse much sooner than the first version, but it's also prone to take a glitch as valid rising edge, as showed in the simulation. I'd stick with the first version then.